# Capturing the snail with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete, tags

I would like to create a system of tags with Ajax. I would use the same system of facebook, That Is, a when you press the scroll function is activated autocomplete with various names of friends. My problem is this: How do I capture the "at sign" using the event "keydown" keyCode and function? I thank the possible help.

```
$(document).on("keydown",'.text-area-commento', function(e)
{
        if(e.keyCode === 64)
        {
            alert("tag");
        }

        if(e.keyCode === 13)
        {
            var id_post = $(this).attr('id');
            var message = $(".commento"+id_post).val();

            if (e.shiftKey) {
                $(this).val( $(this).val() + "<br>" );
            }
            else 
            {
                 ....
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you show what you have so far, so that we can suggest changes. what part are you stuck on? how far have you got?

Comment: The words "snail" and "nut" here are highly confusing, could you reword to elaborate on your needs? Additionally, "tags with Ajax" is concerning and also a bit confusing. Could you re-word your question and give examples of what you've done and what is not working?

Comment: The classic 'snail and nut' problem. textbook

Comment: Do you mean "slug" instead of "snail"? Like: "Slug" - text to use in pre-filled areas. That might make a little more sense.

Comment: I modified the code, excuse the translation. I would like to capture the letters "at sign" with ajax, I did some research and the code seems to be 64, but does not go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Windows alt code](http://fsymbols.com/keyboard/windows/alt-codes/list/) for `@` is 64.

There is no key code for `@`.

The reason for this is because you never type `@` directly, you press <kbd>Shift</kbd> and then press <kbd>2</kbd>.

The key codes for those are `16` and `50`, respectively.
In order to catch these types of key events, you need to have special logic for [modifier keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modifier_key). When a user presses <kbd>Shift</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, etc.) you need to enter a special loop that remembers what was pressed before, and remember that until every key is released.

The sequence you're looking for is:

```
Keydown
Catch key #16
Enter loop
Catch key #50
Trigger tag lookup
Keyup
Exit modifier loop
```

In my opinion, it's easier to just catch that field containing the text character `@`.

If you want to check out a bit of sample code, [here's a little fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rockerest/kq2ka31q/1/) I built for testing. If you press <kbd>2</kbd> in the field **or** you type <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> in the field, it responds the same way.

---

### Edit:

I forgot to mention, browser key events contain special properties indicating shift, control, and alt.

For one single event like <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> your test could look like:

```
if( e.keyCode === 50 && e.shiftKey ){ // do logic for @ }
```

This isn't very scalable, but it would work in small use-cases. I've updated [the fiddle from above](http://jsfiddle.net/rockerest/kq2ka31q/2/) to catch both <kbd>2</kbd> and `@`.